# Angular Js input mask on focus

Tags: angularjs

I have a working directive for phone number input mask

```
.directive('phonenumberDirective', ['$filter', function($filter) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      phonenumberPlaceholder: '=placeholder',
      phonenumberModel: '=model',
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="inputValue" type="tel" placeholder="702-123-1234" class="form-control">',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.inputValue = scope.phonenumberModel;

      scope.$watch('inputValue', function(value, oldValue) {

        value = String(value);
        var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
        scope.phonenumberModel = number;
        scope.inputValue = $filter('phonenumber')(number);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

It will mask number while user type 702-123-1234. How can i show ***-***-____ in input box on focus?
Please find the expected output in the attached image

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific like adding desired behavior with images?

Comment: Thanks, I have attached the image

Comment: You can use [placeholder](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)

Comment: Placeholder i have to show like "702-123-1234" but on hover i have to show like in image

Comment: Got similar solution http://embed.plnkr.co/ZvPHmU/